# Approximation of a Minimum Distance for two Ellipses not touch

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two ellipses with centers $c_1$ and $c_2$ and semi-major axis $m_1$ and $m_2$, respectively. How could I determine a minimum $dist(c_1,c_2)$ to guarantee that two ellipses not touch (or intersect) themselves?

It could be only an approximation. I was thinking of just summing $m_1+m_2$ and if $dist(c_1,c_2)>m_1+m_2$ but I'm not sure if it guarantees that the two ellipses will not touch in any occasion (the ellipses can be rotated with any orientation).

Thanks!

Comment: $m_1$ and $m_2$ are *semi*-major axis, aren't they? Your statement then seems to be a necessary and sufficient condition. Each of the ellipses can be inscribed in a circle with centers $c_{1,2}$ and radus $m_{1,2}$

Comment: Yes, semi-major axis! Thanks for the answer and the correction :).
I'm thinking of a simple way to determine that and could not think anything better than that. To proof using the idea of transforming it in a circle is good! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\operatorname{dist}(c_1,c_2)>m_1+m_2$ is sufficient.

$E_1$ is fully contained in a circle around $c_1$ with radius $m_1$ and likewise $E_2$ in a circle around $c_2$ with radius $m_2$. Since these two circles don't overlp, the ellipses they contain can never overlap, no matter how you rotate them.

Comment: Thanks! If I draw two circles around the foci of an ellipse, which size should it have to cover the entire ellipse? Would the area of these two circles greater than the circle around the center with $r=m1$?

Comment: Or 3 circles around the foci and center that would cover the whole ellipse?

Comment: @user206695: Those are different questions, only remotely related to the original question here, and which deserve more elaboration than what fits into a comment. You should better ask them as separate questions, adding links between questions for reference.